# config @nuxt/tailwind for vue-styleguidist in show example <docs></docs>

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, vue-styleguidist

I need show example in *.vue file project , I use Nuxt and @nuxtjs/tailwindcss
when use tag  for load my example style won't load.
and show in inspect
[image]

I need config my nuxtjs/tailwindcss  for vue-styleguid.config.
Please let me a config for resolve this solation.
this is my styleguide.config.js

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const { resolve } = require("path")

const { getWebpackConfig } = require("nuxt")
const FILTERED_PLUGINS = [
  "WebpackBarPlugin",
  "VueSSRClientPlugin",
  "HotModuleReplacementPlugin",
  "FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin",
  "HtmlWebpackPlugin"
]

const docSiteUrl =
  process.env.DEPLOY_PRIME_URL || "https://vue-styleguidist.github.io"

/** @type import("vue-styleguidist").Config */
module.exports = async () => {
  // get the webpack config directly from nuxt
  const nuxtWebpackConfig = await getWebpackConfig("client", {
    for: "dev"
  })

  const webpackConfig = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        ...nuxtWebpackConfig.module.rules.filter(
          // remove the eslint-loader
          (a) => a.loader !== "eslint-loader"
        )
      ]
    },
    resolve: { ...nuxtWebpackConfig.resolve },
    plugins: [
      ...nuxtWebpackConfig.plugins.filter(
        // And some other plugins that could conflcit with ours
        (p) => !FILTERED_PLUGINS.includes(p.constructor.name)
      )
    ]
  }

  return {
    components: "components/**/*.vue",
    ribbon: {
      text: "Back to examples",
      url: `${docSiteUrl}/Examples.html`
    },
    webpackConfig,
    usageMode: "expand",
    styleguideDir: "dist"
  }
}
```

I need add @nuxt/tailwind in top config.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: Hi @kissu I update my questions.